# Keep from Wearing Holes in the Toes of My Dress Socks

Tags: clothing

Ok, so I've [searched](https://www.google.com/#q=holes+socks+site:stackexchange.com), and searched, but I'm not getting a satisfactory answer to how I can keep from wearing holes in the toes of my dress socks.

Some say to keep your toenails trimmed, others say they do, and they still get holes.

Some say that your shoes make the difference.

What does the lifehacks community say?

I have found these [Kevlar socks](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/713023302/socrates-the-most-clever-socks-ever), which, if they really work, might not be a bad (lifetime) investment.

Is there anything that I can do to keep my dress socks from getting holes in the toes?

@Shoket suggested I add these details from our comments below: The reason I'm asking this question now, is because I recently cleaned house, threw out a bunch of old socks with holes, and bought 8 pairs of new socks, which started getting holes within a month.

Comment: So you're against buying additional pairs of socks ?

Comment: Because I've grown up in a throw away society, I'm not totally against it, but there's this nagging sense that things could be better, which is why I joined this community.

Comment: How long until you get holes? ....after a long time holes are to be expected, and the socks darned or replaced. Are you finding holes in an extraordinarily short amount of time?

Comment: Last pairs I purchased took about a month to get holes.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your shoes. I has shoes which has much friction between the shoe and the socks which tears the socks.

Comment: @user1190941 how often you wear the same pair of socks during this month

Comment: With this latest batch, I cleaned house and bought eight pair (2 four-packs). I agree, the problem most likely has multiple sources, shoes being one of them. Just came here to see if anyone has figured out the combination of solutions that works the best.

Comment: Maybe you should buy higher quality socks? ....I dunno. || tip for you: if you want to be certain that someone sees your response to their comment, write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I only saw your response to my comment because I came back to look at this question for a different reason.

Comment: You might want to [edit] that information (how long it takes to get a hole, how often you wear the socks, etc) into the body of the question, so that (important) information will be more visible. Comments are less visible, and certainly less permanent.

Comment: Will do @Shokhet, thank you for the suggestion. Because it seems to be a universal problem, I have it in my head, that we will be able to find a universal solution, something like: "Buy socks that are half an inch longer than your foot (sized socks), spray them with [fancy magical spray that I haven't found yet] every fifth wash, and ensure your shoes are half a size bigger than you were wearing at age 25. It also helps if you buy [best fabric] socks with [something special on the toe/heel/bottom]."

Comment: I would say your shoes are just a bit too small. Try another brand, or shoes a half-size bigger, or shoes with a bit more space around the toes.

Comment: Sew the holes when they appear. You can easily do it 3-4 times. After that, the socks will likely be worn out everywhere and past recovery anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I would do is wear 2 two slightly thinner pairs of socks. The reason this works:

> - Friction between the shoe and the sock is the cause for the "holey" socks.
> - If you wear two pairs of socks, the thickness of them combined will add extra "cushion", which will reduce friction.
> - The remaining friction is not a problem because only the outside sock will be slightly worn, while the inside sock will remain protected by the outside sock.

Answer (score 3):

You could do as I did: Cut two half-moon shape pieces of cotton cloth big enough to fit over your 5 toes, and then add an inch more to extend over your foot. Stitch them together around the edge to form a glove type covering for your toes, then pull this over the toes. Then, if you pull your socks over each one, the result is no more holes in your socks. You can also leave these inside the socks while the socks get washed!

Answer (score 2):

Try fabric softener. Without it, the fibres in your socks are brittle and more likely to fray and tear

Answer (score 2):

When I get a new pair of socks that I really like, I sew a bit of an old sock in the toe area.  When that bit wears out, I still have the rest of the sock with no holes.  Extends the wearing.

Answer (score 1):

It is the way you walk. You can get creative the two pairs of socks or bullet proof socks. Try not curling your toes upwards with your steps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll pay attention to the principal rotations of my toes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wearing the right size? I get holes in socks that can stretch but are a bit too small. They are always a bit tighter than they could be.

Try dress stocking size that is larger so that there is more room at the toe to reduce the pressure of your toes against the end.

Another indicator of this is that the socks tend to slip down and the heel is tight.

Try a size slightly larger.

Edit: One more thing. Always use a shoehorn to put your dress shoes on. Then, your feet will slide into your shoes smoothly without your heel pulling the extra room for your toes taught. If you can wiggle your toes inside your socks and shoes comfortably, there's less stress on the toe of the stocking and less wear to make a hole.

Answer (score -1):

Stop wearing socks, you can't put holes in something that not there. :D

Comment: Hi MoJoJosef, Welcome to Lifehacks. This is really a popular thing for many people here (Montreal, Canada). This is a "thing" with dress shoes and slip-ons rather than sports footwear. Of course most would agree that this is proper with clogs and sandals.

Comment: Added advantage is that you never walk around with wet socks either.